# show function approaches certain value

Tags: python, simulation

the following is my code for to solve this question :

wrote three functions to Show that as n increases (e.g. with a doubling experiment), from n = 2 to n = 1,000, the value of “day_sim(n)” approaches “sqrt(pi * n / 2)”.

"show that is approaching “sqrt(pi * n / 2)” -> but the graph doesn't look like it is approaching to such sqrt value at all...

Please help me with cracking this

```
import random
from random import randint 
import numpy as np

def randomgen(n):
    np.random.randint(low = 0, high = n)
    return random.randint(0,n-1)

randomgen(100)

def day(n):
    result = []
    random = randomgen(n)
    count =0
    while random not in result:
        result.append(random)
        random = randomgen(n)
        count += 1
    return count
day(100)
    

def day(n):
    result = []
    random = randomgen(n)
    count =0
    while random not in result:
        result.append(random)
        random = randomgen(n)
        count += 1
    return count

def day_sim(n):
    n_trails = 10000  
    for n in range(2,n_trails,50):
        sq_rt = math.sqrt(math.pi*n/2)
        day_sim = day(n)
        print("n =",n,"Absolute difference=",abs(sq_rt - day_sim),"SQ value",sq_rt)
        
        plt.scatter(n,day_sim, color='skyblue')
        plt.scatter(n,sq_rt, color='red')
        plt.xlim(0,10000)
        plt.ylim(0,200)


day_sim(n_trails)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5rwW.png)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to plot the variance as you progress:

variance = the (x - y^)**2/n

```
results = []
for n in range(2000):
  y = day_sim(n)
  x = (math.pi*n/2)**.5
  variance = (x-y)**2/n
  results.append((n, variance))
```

then plot the results and you should see the variance approach zero

Comment: hmm thank you, but it gives me an Maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison - recursion error

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more specific to avoid such error?

Comment: your recurssion may be coming from your `day_sim` function -- please avoid using the variable `day_sim` as both a function name and a list name -- make that update and let me know if you still have issues